# What to do about deleted reCAPTCHA key

Tags: salesforce, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

We have several Salesforce forms that were using reCAPTCHA and when creating a new form, we mistakenly deleted the old key which broke the existing forms. I have created a new key and entered it into Salesforce with the site key and secret key but it does not work. The issue I think is related to the old key which was created by a former employee and we do not have access to its site / secret keys any longer. I am wondering why the new key I created does not work and what I should do to remedy this problem? Many thanks for any tips or advice!

I created a new site key and entered that into Salesforce with the new secret key and used that new  key in the forms. This did not work. The forms work fine without reCAPTCHA but with it enabled, the user does not see an error but the form submission never makes it to Salesforce.